# How to substitute a particular word followed by a alphanumeric / numeric in pandas python?

Tags: python, regex, pandas, text, replace

How do I substitute a particular word(i.e. ABC) followed by a alphanumeric / numeric as shown below in pandas

**Input data**

```
what is ABC s123 doing 77 here?
what is abc  aA574 doing 89 here?
what is ABC-X187 doing here?
what is aBC^984 doing here?
what is Abc647 doing here?
```

**Expected output data**

```
what is ABCS123 doing 77 here?
what is ABCAA574 doing 89 here?
what is ABCX187 doing here?
what is ABC984 doing here?
what is ABC647 doing here?
```

Note: Any alphanumeric can follow ABC. The numbers shown here are just example and dont hardcode the number in the solution.

EDIT1: Just tried the proposed solution. It doesn't work when the special character is space. So please remove the duplicate tag.

EDIT2: Kindly handle the case of ABC as per the question.

Comment: Do you want to remove the spaces or the punctuations?

Comment: Both. Please see the example in the question. I just want to replicate that behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
df['col'] = df['col'].str.replace(r'(?<=ABC)\W+(?=\d\d\d)', '')
```

or

```
df['col'] = df['col'].map(lambda x: re.sub(r'(?<=ABC)\W+(?=\d\d\d)', '', x))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use this code:

```
import re

regex = r"(.*[A-Z]+).*?(\d+.*)"

test_str = """what is ABC 123 doing here?
what is ABC  574 doing here?
what is ABC-187 doing here?
what is ABC^984 doing here?
what is ABC647 doing here?"""

subst = r"\1\2"

result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str)
print (result)
# what is ABC123 doing here?
# what is ABC574 doing here?
# what is ABC187 doing here?
# what is ABC984 doing here?
# what is ABC647 doing here?
```

Details at regex101: https://regex101.com/r/gGK8fJ/2

Comment: Instead of "what" at the beginning of the sentence it could be any word. Please keep that in mind. Will this solution work then? I don't see you hard coding ABC so just checking

Comment: Let check, and tell me. If has any problems, I will update my solution for you!

Comment: This works! However I only want the substitution to happen for word starting with abc only. Could you please update your solution to reflect the same?

Comment: You can set it in character set ([ ... ]). Example with this: `regex = r"(.*[A-C]+).*?(\d+.*)"`, just works with word starting with A --> C (mean A, B, or C)

Answer (score 2):

from the documentation of [Series.str.replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html)

```
s = pd.Series("""what is ABC 123 doing here?
what is ABC  574 doing here?
what is ABC-187 doing here?
what is ABC^984 doing here?
what is ABC647 doing here?""".split("\n"))

pattern = r"ABC.*?(\d+)"
s.str.replace(pattern, r"ABC \1")
```

> ```
> 0    what is ABC 123 doing here?
> 1    what is ABC 574 doing here?
> 2    what is ABC 187 doing here?
> 3    what is ABC 984 doing here?
> 4    what is ABC 647 doing here?
> dtype: object
> ```